# "I've never seen an elephant" vs. "I've never seen any elephant"

Tags: articles

In these sentences:

> **A:** I've never seen **an** elephant yet.
>   **B:** I've never seen **any** elephant yet.

Which article fits better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither article will improve the sentence. You have a clash between *have never* (negated experiential perfective) and *yet* (implying that a sighting is expected soon).

You can say *I haven't seen any elephant yet* in a situation where you are expecting to see one or more elephants (but it doesn't say anything about your lifetime experience). You can say *I have never seen an elephant* when you want to speak about your own life experience (perhaps explaining why you are excited about a potential sighting).

Comment: I think you've nailed it. We'd use _any_ on a safari, but _an_ when we have yet to see an elephant in our lifetime.

Comment: so if i remove "yet" from the sentence, the only true way is to use "an". Am i right ?

Comment: *Any* ***elephants*** (plural).

Comment: @berkyykreb you'd say *I've never seen any elephant* if you want to be emphatic, for example if people are skeptical of your earlier claims of not having seen an elephant. maybe they thought you were deceiving them originally because you had seen a Burmese elephant, though most people are thinking of African elephants; and you want to clarify. But the point is it's a very specific circumstance that it's felicitous to say that.

Comment: @jlovegren Do you mean **You have a clash between .....** or am I missing something?

Comment: @RonaldSole thanks for noting the typo.